# Set applicationIdSuffix for specific flavor-buildType combination in Gradle 4.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have different build types and different flavor dimensions in my app. I want to add a specific flavor suffix to an application ID only for one specific build type.

E.g. for `stageApi` flavor and `beta` build type combination I'd like to add suffixes `.stageapi` and `.beta` so the result application ID will be `my.application.stageapi.beta`, but for `debug` and `release` I don't want to do that (I'd like to have `my.application.debug` and `my.application` without api suffix).

I've had this code before and it worked just fine:

```
    productFlavors {

        ... 

        beta {
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def name = variant.getName()
        if (name.contains("StageApiBeta")) {
            def mergedFlavor = variant.mergedFlavor
            mergedFlavor.setApplicationIdSuffix(".stageapi")
        }
    }
```

But after upgrading to Gradle plugin 4.1 it stopped working. It doesn't throw any error, but the resulting application ID is `my.application.beta`, without `.stageapi`.

I tried different approaches but I just can't figure out how to do it now. I seems also that 4.2 will have other API changes as well, but I'd like to make it work in 4.1 also.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue after upgrading to 4.1.1, mergedFlavor.setApplicationId still works so if I can't find a better solution I'll just concatenate all the applicationIds and set them that way.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flavorDimensions` and set different suffix to your variants.

```
flavorDimensions "dimen1" "dimen2"
productFlavors {
   beta {
     applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
     dimension "dimen1"
   }
   stageapi {
     applicationIdSuffix ".stageapi"
     dimension "dimen2"
   }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'd like to have it only for particular combinations. With this approach it will be applied to all of them. E.g. debug-stageApi combination will result in `my.application.stageapi.debug`, which I don't want.